# Solr 4.6.1 Number format exception while adding records

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I am getting the below exception after Migrating from Solr 4.4.1 to Solr 4.6.1. The schema declares the field ca_xyz as 'tlong'.

Here is the schema definition of ca_xyz

```
<field name="ca_xyz" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=CA:86] Error adding field 'ca_xyz'='java.math.BigDecimal:1912957986' msg=For input string: "java.math.BigDecimal:1912957986"
        at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:167)
        at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:77)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:215)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:571)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:707)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:437)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
        at org.apache.solr.update.PeerSync.handleUpdates(PeerSync.java:496)
        at org.apache.solr.update.PeerSync.handleResponse(PeerSync.java:327)
        at org.apache.solr.update.PeerSync.sync(PeerSync.java:252)
        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:391)
        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.run(RecoveryStrategy.java:247)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "java.math.BigDecimal:1912957986"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.createField(TrieField.java:599)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.createFields(TrieField.java:650)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:47)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:118)
```

Comment: Was the *tlong* field defined as *TrieLongField* ?

Comment: Yes.  The same schema was working in Solr 4.4.1.  Not sure what changed in Solr 4.6

Comment: Perhaps to try TrieIntField? You might want to post the revelent configurations in the schema

Comment: You may need to convert BigDecimal to long in the docs you post

Comment: I have added the Schema Definition to the post.  The docs I post are coming from the Oracle Database.  The filed is defined as a number in the table.  This worked perfectly in Solr 4.4, so I don't think this is something to do with the field definitions.

Comment: Would you mind to post relevant configurations about type="double" ?

Comment: I have edited and added the configuration.